# Show that there exist infinitely many primes of the form $6k-1$

Tags: number-theory, infinity, congruences, divisibility

This is a question on the text book that i have no way to deal with. Can anyone help me?

Show that there exist infinitely many primes of the form $6k-1$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507160/finding-infinetely-many-primes-in-three-different-forms-of-prime-numbers-below/507173#507173

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Suppose $p_1, \dots, p_n$ be all the primes of the form $6k-1$, then $N = 6p_1\dots p_n-1$ is also of the form $6k-1$. If $N$ is divisible by a prime, it must be $3$ or of the form $6k+1$ (why?). Show that these can't actually be factors, so $N$ is prime.

Comment: Did you mean $6k - 1$? And I'm not sure how clear that $N$ only has factors of that form.

Comment: No, I mean $6k+1$. It is not immediately clear that any factors are of that form, it takes a bit of thought.